# How to define a `from ... import *' api seperate from __all__ in a module?

Tags: python, api, python-3.x

I have a module which is split roughly in half between utility type functions and core api functions.  I need to have all of them in `__all__` in order to have `help()` be useful, and also to specify which of the many functions/classes/etc in the module are for external use, but I also want to support `from mymodule import *` as a way to get just the core functionality into other modules.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost.  While you can't have `__all__` do double duty in this way, you can add your own virtual api module which can then be imported...

```
class fake_module(object):
    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.name = name
        self.__all__ = []
        all_objects = globals()
        for name in args:
            self.__dict__[name] = all_objects[name]
            self.__all__.append(name)
    def register(self):
        sys.modules["%s.%s" % (__name__, self.name)] = self

    fake_module('api', 'class1', 'class2', 'func3', 'exception4').register()
```

Then in the other modules instead of `from mymodule import *` you can do `from mymodule.api import *` to get just the desired subset while still keeping everything in a single module.

**Note**: `from ... import *` is not usually good practice, and should be used with great care and only with modules/packages that explicity state that they have been designed with such usage in mind.

Comment: There's no real need to go all crazy here... just make a separate file called 'api' and import the subset of functions into it, and then import it into the module's __init__.py.

Comment: @Dave: modules are single files, and as such do not have `__init__.py`s. packages are the ones that *must* have an `__init__.py` file, and can have other files as well.  The library I am developing fits comfortably into a single file (yes, I tried the package route for it, and eventually switched back to a single file/module layout).

Comment: fair enough.  When you assume... : )

Answer (score 4):

Ethan, your `fake_module` is likely better accomplished with plain old python. Just move your code into a directory setup:

```
mymodule
    __init__.py
    api.py
    util.py
    _mymodule.py
```

Where `_mymodule.py` contains your current code.

In your `__init__.py`:

```
from _mymodule import *
```

In you're `api.py`

```
# explicity import only those api classes you want to expose
# this will allow you to call `from mymodule.api import *`
import from _mymodule ApiClass1
import from _mymodule ApiClass2
# etc
```

Do the same for your `util.py`

```
# explicity import only those util classes you want to expose
# this will allow you to call `from mymodule.util import *`
import from _mymodule UtilClass1
import from _mymodule UtilClass2
# etc
```

So now you can:

```
# import everything willy nilly for your help()
from mymodule import *

# or import only the "public" values from api and util
from mymodule.api import *
from mymodule.util import *
```

Breaking up your code like this can be useful for organizing a largish module that you still want to be able to access from a top level namespace. But I would have to agree with `brandizzi` that using `from mymodule import *` in code that is using this module is generally a bad idea. What you gain in ease of importing you lose in transparency of the code that is using those imports.

Comment: Thorough, complete answer that details the way it is normally done.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a way to do it - at least not a clean way. Even the Python official modules have a lot of util functions appearing in its documentation. What I would do, if the separation is important, is to create two different modules. Anyway, to use `from module import *` is not a good practice and I would not recommend you to do it, much less to design your modules for fitting such practice :)

Comment: For user-defined utility modules it is rather good practice imho.

Comment: @Evpok what is an user-defined utility module? Are they modules to be used in the Python console?

Comment: I meant some modules with shortcuts or constants used everywhere in an application, default values, magic numbers, dirty hacks...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have what you want:  `import *` behavior is defined by `__all__`.

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but pretty darn close.  `from mymodule.api import *` is good enough.